# How do I configure my graphics drivers?

Tags: drivers, configuration, monitors, graphics

I'm running Linux Mint 9 gnome on a Toshiba Satellite A105-S4211

With this,

inxi -G Graphics: Card Intel Mobile 945GM/GMS 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller X.Org 1.7.6 Res: 1280x800@60.0hz GLX Renderer Mesa DRI Intel 945GM GEM 20091221 2009Q4 x86/MMX/SSE2 GLX Version 1.4 Mesa 7.7.

And I want to know how to configure the monitor/graphic/video/driver/gamma settings.

What I really want to do is change the gamma settings on my computer. I was told that I can do this using the video card driver.

I want to know how to do that.

Comment: I vaguely recall an old program called xvidtune that might be what you want.

Comment: yes. That works. When I ran the xgamma man page I saw it. It works but I am too afraid to use it. I wish I could just figure out how to work with icc profiles .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to adjust the gamma using the `xgamma` command.

Comment: Thanks Amazed. I can. And there is also xvidtune. After running it there is a warning and so I decided it was too dangerous for ignorant me to use.

Comment: Now I can solve reCAPTCHA images on my (very dim!) CRT screen thanks to this utility.

Answer (score 1):

I think the program you are looking for is `xvidtune`.

Comment: Yes. That was it.